# Is it possible to support iPad HD only device while releasing app to Apple AppStore?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, cocos2d-x

**Update:**
iPad HD : iPad Retina (high resolution) (2048x1536)
iPad : Medium resolution (1024x768)
iphone : Low Resolution (below 1024x768)

I'm a c++ developer and mostly develop our apps on cocos2d-x to support cross platform.
Since we are supporting all device resolutions, we need to ship all resource contents (iphone, ipad and ipadhd) in one universal binary for Apple AppStore. The accumulative size is 38MB for our app and its already in the Apple AppStore.

We have been thinking about spliting app to support for iPhone, iPad and iPadHD separately. But in `"xcode > Target > Devices"`, I can see only three options `iPhone`, `iPad` and `Universal`.

#### What I'm aware of?

- If I go to support iPhone and iPad individually, I need two different names like `AppName` and `AppName for iPad`.
- We can not use the existing name and bundle id, and continue to support only one of the target devices if it is already a universal binary.

#### What I want to accomplish?

- I want to have three different packages for same app with three different names(or bundle id's) like `AppName`, `AppName for iPad` and `AppName HD` for Apple AppStore.
- Packing only resources required to support the individual target device (I can use python scripting to remove irrelevant resource assets).
- Whenever there is any update, release for individual target devices.

#### What is the issue?

- How to support iPad HD only? I don't want to bundle ipad(12MB) and ipadhd(17MB) resources in one binary. Is it possible to accomplish this task?
- If the above problem has no solution and I choose target device as `iPad`, Do I need to support iPad and iPad HD both?

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly you mean by “iPad HD”? Do you mean a retina iPad (2048x1536) as opposed to the original iPad (1024x768)?

Comment: Yes Todd, You are right.

Comment: From a user's point of view this is a really terrible idea. Apps these days are almost expected to be universal, you should not have the user to be aware of and make a choice between the types of your app, especially if they aren't free. Moreover your chances of your app moving to the top 100 of any chart are split by three (at least). You also provide no reason why you would want to do this split (except "I don't want to..."), maybe that reason is the thing we should actually comment on or help with, if it's technical in nature.

Comment: Really, 38MB for a universal app isn't all that bad. Your app is fine the way it is without having to split it up. Since your universal app is already in the app store, you'll lose a lot of users when transitioning them to the screen-specific apps.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I agree with you. Sorry for skipping this. The reason is: We have our app published to Android Play Store too and we are trying to support different resolution devices with Android multiple apk support so that we can reduce the size of app and it could reach many users with low internet bandwidth. So, I was looking for something like "Multiple APK" support for AppStore.

Comment: @BergQuester Yeah, 38 MB is good. Previously it reached to 55MB. We put some efforts in audio and png/jpeg compression and reached to this goal. We have been thinking to split app because in cocos2dx, we need to bundle all resources in one binary. So we have been thinking that if its okay to ship different binaries for all three different resolution devices(iPhone, iPad, iPad Retina). Its just for app size reduction purpose. In itunes connect Can we can provide different packages for for different devices? Does AppStore takes care of installing appropriate package for appropriate device?

Comment: As @LearnCocos2D said this is a bad idea and it is against the "Apple Way".  Apple doesn't want users to have to worry about whether they have a retina or non-retina device when installing software.  When a user upgrades from a non-retina to a retina device they expect the software to automatically take advantage of their new hardware.  If you want to reduce your download size, perhaps you could have your app load the resources from a web server on first launch?

Comment: Does anyone know THE ANSWER TO THE QUESTION?  CAN IT BE DONE?

Comment: No, the App store does not have anything equivalent to Android's "Multiple APK". You can release different versions as completely separate apps if you can justify it to Apple's review board, but you cannot release separate versions for different devices as one app. If you really must reduce the size more, you can download assets at the first launch, but at 38MB I really don't think this is worth the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manish, one solution is to "simply" **download** the large images after the user purchases the app.  It's common with games that that happens.  First you download the app off the app store, and then it says "Loading dragon costumes!" or whatever and then it downloads a half gig of dragon costumes.

Whatever platform you are using , Unity3D or whatever, there is usually a trivial way to do this (since most games do it).

BTW two points, (a) 38mb is nothing for a game, so forget that. and (b) you are **very smart** to only target users with modern machines.  Users with old machines are cheap, they don't pay for stuff.  It's all but pointless supporting anything less than iOS7, for example, unless you are the biggest most world-famous games.

Comment: Ahmen to this @Joe Blow